# C++ variable value not changing

Tags: c++, variables

I'm using the following code (it's been super simplified to get to the root of my problem).

```
#include <iostream>
namespace std;

int user;
int submit(int);

int main() {

    user = 1;
    submit(user);

    user = 2;
    submit(user);

    return(0);
}

int submit(int user) {

    if (user = 1) {
        printf("1");
    } else if (user = 2) {
        printf("2");
    }
    return(0);

}
```

I thought that this would print out "12" but instead I'm getting "11". Isn't the variable "user" getting redefined before the function is called for the second time?

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `==`, not `=` to check the values of `user`.  You're overwriting the values (with `=`) instead of comparing them (with `==`).

Answer (score 6):

You are using `=` not `==` in your function body.

```
if (user = 1) { //This assigns user the value of 1 and then prints 1
         printf("1");
```

The correct test condition should be :

```
if (user == 1) { //This checks the value of user and then prints if the condition is true
         printf("1");
```

---

While compiling, if using `gcc`, adding the option `-Wall` is helpful in such cases as it gives you a warning about assignments in test conditions.

Comment: Got it! Thanks. I need to keep a closer eye on those equal signs :)

Answer (score 1):

As answered by the experts, You are using `=` instead of using `==` in your function body that's why you are getting wrong output.

Here, I would like to clear your concept why it happens:
I hope you know the difference between assignment operator and equality operator. If not, I'm going to describe it briefly.

**Assignment operator (=):**

The assignment operator assigns a value to a variable. e.g.

`user = 1;`

This statement assigns the integer value 1 to the variable `user`.

**This statement will always be executed which indicates that it is logically `TRUE` statement** (assuming variable `user` is declared already).

As there is no comparison or something like that, so if we use Assignment operator(=) as a condition, it will always return `TRUE` or `1`

**Equality operator(==):**

The equality operator is used to compare two values to know if they are equal or not.

`user == 1;`

This statement will compare the value of variable `user` with `1` and it will return `TRUE` if the value of `user` is `1` otherwise it will return `FALSE`.

**RESULT:** Assignment operator will always return `TRUE` but comparison operator may return `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Now coming back to your code:

```
int submit(int user) {
//as you're using assignmnt operator this if condition will always true regardless of input
    if (user = 1) {    
       printf("1");
//because if condition is true, it will never go into else if condition
    } else if (user = 2) {
       printf("2");
    }
    return(0);
}
```

So, actually, whenever you call this function, it will print `1` each time regardless of the value of `user` passed to this function. Since, you have called this function 2 times. Therefore, it will print `11`.